# Perspective projection math help?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, projection

I have points X,Y,Z and have a camera at Cx,Cy,Cz. Assuming the camera is not rotated and is facing the -Z direction and is at 0,0,0. What would the math be for projecting the X,Y,and Z values onto the 2d projection plane that is at a distance of znear from the camera. This is also assuming that X,Y,and Z will be in the camera's view.

Comment: This might do better in [math.se]

Comment: K i'll try it there.